# Me salta un error Undefined array key "alumno"

Tags: php, html, sql, array, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un formulario el cual muestra un arreglo después de pedir el nombre del usuario pero me dice

> Undefined array key "alumno" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Proyecto2on line 20  Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: mysqli_query(): Argument #2 ($query) cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Proyecto2\consulta.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Proyecto2\consulta.php(21): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Proyecto2\consulta.php on line 21

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Consulta</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
            datos del compañero<br>
            <input type="text" name="alumno"><br>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="consulta" value="consultar datos">
    </form>
    <button><a href="index.html">regresar</a></button>
    <?php
        $inc=include ("config.php");

        $registro=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT `alumno`, `semestre`, `especialidad`, `matricula` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `alumno`=$_POST[alumno]");
        $resultado= mysqli_query($conexion,$registro);
        if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){
            echo"nombre completo".$reg['alumno']."<br>";
            echo"semestre".$reg['especialidad']."<br>";
            echo"especialidad".$reg['matricula']."<br>";
            echo"matricula".$reg['semestre']."<br>";
            }
        else{
            echo"no existe un alumno con ese nombre";
        }   
        mysqli_close($conexion);



        ?>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿existe el campo `alumno` en la tabla `usuarios` de la base de datos? Quizás te confundiste y el campo es `alumnos`.

Answer (score 1):

En tu consulta cuando pasas el POST te faltan los apostrofes para indicar el indice `$_POST['alumno']`

Te recomiendo primero pasar el dato a una variable y agregar   `mysqli_real_escape_string()` para limpiar el dato y evitar SQL inject

`$alumno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['alumno']);`